# Scrambled number conversion for numbers with 10 or more digits

Tags: haskell

This is a quite simple piece of code. It takes an integer and decomposes its decimal digits using quotient and remainder. On each call, it prints a line with r characters 'I', where r is the last digit, then calls itself with the quotient as its new argument.

```
decToUnary 0 = return ()
decToUnary n = let (q, r) = quotRem n 10 in 
    do  
      putStrLn (take r "IIIIIIIIII")
      decToUnary q
```

It works correctly for numbers with less than 10 digits, but for 10 or more digits it scrambles the output. What am I doing wrong, and why does it work this way?
Here are some examples of output, the first is correct, the second is wrong:

```
*Main> decToUnary 5432
II
III
IIII
IIIII

*Main> decToUnary 5432101234
IIIIIIII
III
IIIIIIIII
III
III
I
IIIIIII
III
I
I
```

Comment: Factoring side note: `decToUnary` should really be a pure `Integer -> [String]` function.  You can then print the list with `mapM_ putStrLn (decToUnary whatever)`.

Comment: `enrique` note that in taking `dave4420`'s advice and alterning the signature to `Integer -> IO ()` you will need to change the line `take  r "IIIIIIIIII"` to `take (fromInteger r) "IIIIIIIIII"` since the Prelude `take` function uses the fixed length `Int`

Comment: Note: with `Integer`, you can't directly use the remainder `r` as argument for `take`. You could use `take (fromInteger r) "III..."` then or `import Data.List` and use `genericTake`.

Comment: Thanks to all. In fact, the signature decToUnary :: Int -> IO () is the one choosen by the compiler. I think that the compiler would not have to decide type optimizations, but instead compute the most generic and safe type for an expression, because one important criteria in the rest of the language design was to avoid side-effects. @thomas, this is my Haskell Prime proposal.

Comment: @enrique yes, because you used `take`. It expects an `Int`, and that knowledge got propagated back to your function's type. You could insulate it by using `fromIntegral r` instead of just `r`. Then compiler would assign `Int` type to the result of `fromIntegral r`. That would only constrain `r`'s type as being in `Integral` type class. Try it, with such changed code and w/out the explicit type signature.

Comment: also, better use `(cycle "I")` to provide unlimited supply of "I"s. maybe you'd like to change the conversion base some day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an integer overflow question. `maxBound :: Int` is 2147483647 (on 32-bit machines), so values greater than that overflow.

Use `Integer` instead of `Int`: `Integer` is not a fixed length integer so it won't overflow.

**Edit:** As applicative notes, you will then need to replace the `take r "IIIIIIIIII"` with `take (fromIntegral r) "IIIIIIIIII"` or `genericTake r "IIIIIIIIII"`; I'd prefer `genericReplicate r 'I'`.

[`genericTake`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3agenericTake) and [`genericReplicate`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html#v%3agenericReplicate) are both in Data.List.

Comment: The recent spike in these types of questions makes me think that Cryptol and Habit have it right - don't let people claim literals have a type that mean they {over,under}flow.  Time for a new Haskell Prime proposal!

Comment: Ok, now I understand. The problem is on the type signature of 'quotRem'. The argument of `take` will always be less than 10 (not overflow problem), but `quotRem` assigns the same type for the two inputs and the two outputs: `quotRem :: Integral a => a -> a -> (a, a)`. It would avoid problems if it was `quotRem :: (Integral a1, Integral a2) => a1 -> a2 -> (a1, a2)`, because the rest of integer division will always be less than the divisor, and the quotient will be less that the dividend (the same holds for `divMod`).